# web.config transform: Add XML comment to indicate which configuration was used

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Using web.config transforms, I want to make sure and include a comment at top of the resulting web.config to indicate which transform file(configuration) was used to generate it.

I don't see a way to include comments from the transform files, can this be done?

EDIT:

It appears that all comments in the transform files are stripped.

Comment: What happens if you just add a comment?

Comment: Comments in the transform file are not merged into the actual web.config.

Comment: [Vote](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2578637-allow-inserting-comments-with-web-config-transform) for this feature to be include in Visual Studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following does not directly answer how to add or preserve comments, but it might get you toward the goal of knowing which transform was used. Admittedly, it feels a little strange, so keep your eyes open for other answers. It's just the first thing that came to mind.

I don't know of a way to preserve the comments from transforms, but you could always insert a dummy application setting to deliver the information. The app doesn't actually have to use it for anything =p

Here I have it being inserted by the transform, assuming it isn't in the main web.config. You could just as easily do a Replace.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="WhichTransformWasUsed" value="Production" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: As discussed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22812595/3507333), adding comments only works by adding or replacing a parent element. However, your solution works great since all I wanted was a quick sanity check at the top of my config file!

Comment: I'm also using visually-distinctive format that stands out among the other <add> entries, specifically:
`<add key="build_config_name" value="############################## DEBUG ##############################"/>`
That makes it very easy to notice in the resulting/transformed .config file