# Adding comments using XDT-Transform

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xdt-transform

I am using XDT-Transform in Visual Studio 2010 to generate multiple config files.

Xml transformation is working fine. But I cannot seem to find way to carry comments from an xml transform file to final file.

Just like there is `Insert` transform for adding config settings, is there anyway to add comments? Without comments I may have to give up on the whole transform approach.

Comment: [Vote](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2578637-allow-inserting-comments-with-web-config-transform) for this feature to be include in Visual Studio

Answer (score 9):

I've found a possible solution for you.

It is only necessary to denote something as being an Insert at the highest level you are adding it.  After that you may just add elements like you would normally.

Meaning this doesn't work to bring over your comment

```
<appSettings>
    <!--My Secret Encryption Key-->
    <add key="ENCRYPT_KEY" value="hunter2" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
</appSettings>
```

But this would

```
<appSettings xdt:Transform="Remove" />
<appSettings xdt:Transform="Insert" >
    <!--My Secret Encryption Key-->
    <add key="ENCRYPT_KEY" value="hunter2"/>
</appSettings>
```

Nothing else requires a transform as it copies over the element entirely.

**Upside**: You get your comments and don't have to insert `xdt:Transform="Insert"` into every key element.

**Downside**: You end up destroying the section entirely and re add it which ends up appending it to the bottom of your Web.config.  If the change in total formatting is okay then awesome.  Also it requires you recreate the entire section which could increase the size of your transforms.

Comment: You can use InsertAfter and insertBefore to specify the locations of your added sections if you're worried about where they appear in the file, e.g. xdt:Transform="InsertAfter(/configuration/appSettings)"

Comment: You can also denote xdt:Transform="Replace" , sometimes if you try to remove and insert the highest level, visual studio warns you that it's not possible to remove the highest level.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't exactly what you want, but I find it useful once in a while.
XmlTransform will add comments if they are contained in an added element.

e.g.

```
<appSettings>
<remove key="comment" value="" xdt:Transform="Insert"><!-- this comment will appear in the transformed config file! --></remove>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not possible without writing code.

However, my current solution is to extent the XDT Transform library, by basically following the link: [Extending XML (web.config) Config transformation](http://sedodream.com/2010/09/09/ExtendingXMLWebconfigConfigTransformation.aspx)

And here is my example of `CommentAppend`, `CommentPrepend` which take comment text as input parameter, as I believe otherwise `Insert` itself can't work as  the comment you would put your `xdt:Transform="Insert"` will be ignored by XDT Transform as it is comment.

```
internal class CommentInsert: Transform
{
    protected override void Apply()
    {
        if (this.TargetNode != null && this.TargetNode.OwnerDocument != null)
        {
            var commentNode = this.TargetNode.OwnerDocument.CreateComment(this.ArgumentString);
            this.TargetNode.AppendChild(commentNode);
        }
    }
}

internal class CommentAppend: Transform
{
    protected override void Apply()
    {
        if (this.TargetNode != null && this.TargetNode.OwnerDocument != null)
        {
            var commentNode = this.TargetNode.OwnerDocument.CreateComment(this.ArgumentString);
            this.TargetNode.ParentNode.InsertAfter(commentNode, this.TargetNode);
        }
    }
}
```

And the input `web.Release.config`:

```
<security xdt:Transform="CommentPrepend(comment line 123)" >
</security>
<security xdt:Transform="CommentAppend(comment line 123)" >
</security>
```

And the output:

```
  <!--comment line 123--><security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="NWebsecConfig" />
      <add segment="Logs" />
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security><!--comment line 123-->
```

I am currently using Reflector to look at Microsoft.Web.XmTransform comes with Visual Studio V12.0 to figure out how it works, but probably it's better to look at the [source code itself](https://xdt.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That's a really great solution; good to learn a bit deeper how the transform works.
A further improvement could perhaps be to add a carriage return after the prepend comment and before the append comment. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware adding comments using XDT-Transform is not possible I'm afraid.

At least it doesn't appear to be mentioned within the [XDT-Transform documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I built an [extension for XDT](https://github.com/akarzazi/xdt-extensions) to handle comment injection and other related tasks.

You can try it [online](https://akarzazi.github.io/xdt-playground).

Comment: can you use it as a postbuild task in VS?